# Replace text in multiple files BUT keep the original

Tags: c#, winforms

(Visual Studio C# 2010, Windows Form App) 
Hey i want to replace some words in .txt files. I know how to do that but I dont know how keep the original file as well. I want to output the modified text to a file of a different name to the input file.  Otherwise, there is no easy way to make a comparison, since the original file gets overwritten...

This is what ive got so far.

```
this.openFileDialog1.Filter =`enter code here`"TEXT (*.xml;*.txt|";
this.openFileDialog1.Multiselect = true;
this.openFileDialog1.Title = "My text editor";
DialogResult dr = openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();

if (dr == DialogResult.OK)
{
    foreach (String file in openFileDialog1.FileNames)
    {
        try
        {
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(file);
            string content = reader.ReadToEnd();
            reader.Close();

            content = Regex.Replace(content, "play", "player");
            content = Regex.Replace(content, "game", "gamer");
            content = Regex.Replace(content, "walk", "walking");
            StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(file);
            writer.Write(content); writer.Close(); 
        }
        catch
        { // The user lacks appropriate permissions to read files, discover paths, etc. MessageBox.Show("Security error. Please contact your administrator for details.\n\n" + "Error message: Not found" ); } {
        }
      }
}
```

Comment: Just provide a different file to your `StreamWriter`. Now you provide the same file as you use for your `StreamReader`.

Answer (score 3):

In your code you are using the *same* file for reading and writing - you simply need to write to a different file from the one you are reading from.

```
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(file);
string content = reader.ReadToEnd();
reader.Close();

...

StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(some_other_file); // <--- here
writer.Write(content); 
writer.Close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to do this:

using System.Text.RegularExpressions;